# Cassandra: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : D:\cassandra\lib\jamm-0.3.2

Tags: java, maven, cassandra

Been trying to build Apache Cassandra using Ant. The build is successful, but the Cassandra server won't start using `bin\cassandra` because of the error: `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : D:\cassandra\lib\jamm-0.3.2`.

Here is the environment setup:

- JDK 8 bin directory added to PATH
- JAVA_HOME is set to the JDK 8 directory
- CASSANDRA_HOME is set to D:\cassandra, where I cloned the repo
- D:\cassandra\lib\jamm-0.3.2.jar exists

Just in case I tried recloning the repo in another directory, rebuilding, but same error.

Checking the output when building, I noticed warnings like this one, I don't know if it is relevant.

```
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.perfkit.sjk.parsers:sjk-jfr5:pom:
0.5:compile' is invalid.
[artifact:dependencies]
[artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the c
urrent build.
```

Any idea of what else I could test? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I set the environment variables PATH, CASSANDRA_HOME and JAVA_HOME using the `set` command.

By going to the system parameters and changing the user variables, it worked. I changed those three at the same time so I am not sure which one was blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue, too, when running Cassandra from my build directory.

What you'll want to do is to "deploy" your build (target) to a different directory, and set your `CASSANDRA_HOME` to that.  Essentially, you'll want to emulate the how the "delivered" directory structure looks, ensuring that subdirs like `bin/`, `conf/` and `lib/` are at the same directory level.

Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Sould the build directory contain `bin/` and `conf/` ? The one generated by ant, whitout touching to the `build.xml` only contains the following subdirs: `classes/`, `jacoco/`, `lib/`, `test/` and `tools/`.